# ESP8266 читает JSON, но не читает PHP файл

Tags: php, c++, json, arduino, esp8266

Есть код для `ESP8266`, который парсит данные на моем сайте и выполняет включение/выключение светильника. Когда это был статичный `JSON` файл, оно все обрабатывало без проблем. Но когда я все перенес в `PHP` файл, который динамически обновляет данные и выводит их в `JSON` формате, скрипту не получается его прочитать. В чем может быть проблема?

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#define pin 5

const char* ssid     = "ssid";  
const char* password = "password";

const char* host     = "www.site.ru"; // domain  
String path          = "/lightAPI.php";  

void setup() {  
  pinMode(pin, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(pin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  delay(10);
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  int wifi_ctr = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
  Serial.println("IP address: " + WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {  
  WiFiClient client;
  const int httpPort = 80;
  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }

  client.print(String("GET ") + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + 
               "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n");


  delay(2000); // wait for server to respond

  // read response
  String section="header";
  while(client.available()){
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    // Serial.print(line);
    // we’ll parse the HTML body here
    if (section=="header") { // headers..
      Serial.print("");
      if (line=="\n") { // skips the empty space at the beginning 
        section="json";
      }
    }
    else if (section=="json") {  // print the good stuff
      section="ignore";
      String result = line.substring(1);

      // Parse JSON
      int size = result.length() + 1;
      char json[size];
      result.toCharArray(json, size);
      StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;
      JsonObject& json_parsed = jsonBuffer.parseObject(json);
      if (!json_parsed.success())
      {
        Serial.println("parseObject() failed");
        return;
      }

      // Make the decision to turn off or on the LED
      if (strcmp(json_parsed["light"], "OFF") == 0) {
        digitalWrite(5, HIGH); 
        Serial.println("LED OFF");
      }
      else {
        digitalWrite(5, LOW);
        Serial.println("LED ON");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Файл `PHP`

```php
<?php
$status = file_get_contents('txt/lightStatus.txt');

$json = array('light' => $status, 'time' => date("G"));

echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Вот какие ответы я получаю от сервера

```html
//Такой ответ получаю, когда запрашиваю JSON файл
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx admin
Date: Fri, 16 Jun 2017 20:49:26 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 40
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Fri, 16 Jun 2017 17:03:12 GMT
X-Cache: HIT from Backend
Accept-Ranges: bytes


//А такой ответ, когда PHP
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx admin
Date: Fri, 16 Jun 2017 20:51:42 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: У  функции http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php есть много флагов, попробуйте разные. Посмотрите ошибки которые возвращает.

Comment: @E_p, к сожалению, не помогло ничего

Comment: Сделайте вывод идентичный тому что работает и сравните по-буквенно - например, в https://www.diffchecker.com

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, копирую из строки браузера вывод PHP, вставляю в JSON и все работает. Заметил что браузер JSON файлу добавляет <pre> теги, их тоже попытался выводить в PHP, но это не помогло.

Comment: Из какой строки? У вас что, делается редирект, где в строку адреса вставляется JSON? Попробуйте добавить header('Content-Type: application/json'); перед echo строкой.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, тэги появились, но скрипт все равно не видит этого JSON.

Comment: @StartProg Используйте wget, чтобы посмотреть, что возвращает скрипт.

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics, добавил, что возвращает и их разницу. Не могу понять, что происходит с ним.

Comment: Это заголовок, но проблема- то не в нём. Что с контентом?

Answer (score -1):

PHP файл выполняется на стороне сервера, а не клиента, esp8266 не сможет выполнить php скрипт на своей стороне.
Используй js и Json.

Comment: Если вы внимательно прочитаете вопрос, то увидите, что php запускается на сервере